# Dynamic Updating CreateDialog Problem

Tags: dynamic

In this code, one cannot close the dialog window:

```
{TogglerBar[Dynamic[x], Range[5]], Dynamic[x],  Dynamic[CreateDialog[x]]}
```

If I use `DynamicModule` this way, the dialog window will not pop up when it was closed and re-chosen some values.

```
{TogglerBar[Dynamic[y],Range[5]],Dynamic[y],DynamicModule[{y=y},CreateDialog[y]]}
```

So how to make the created dialog window could be closed and reopen when click to set different values by `TogglerBar`

Comment: In the first example you give, you can close the dialog. It just so happens a new one is created whenever you close an old one. You can notice this through the names changing in the output. In the second case, you forgot your `Dynamic` around `CreateDialog` if that was what you are asking about. Perhaps you are simply looking for `CreateDialog[Dynamic@y]` ?

Comment: @jVincent Yeah, The first case just generate too many NotebookNojects.
The second case: what I'm really looking for is How to Reopen the Dialog via Clicking in the TogglerBar.

CreateDialog[Dynamic[y]] or Dynamic[CreateDialog[y]] seems doesn't work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this fully answers your question, but here is a method of using the `Dynamic` to check if a dialog is already open and reopen it if it has been closed:

```
DynamicModule[{nb = CreateDialog[Dynamic@y]},
 TogglerBar[
  Dynamic[y, (y = #;If[Not@MemberQ[Notebooks[], nb],nb = CreateDialog[Dynamic@y]]) &], 
 Range[5]]]
```

Comment: haha, that's right - thanks.